# Why does a LoginContext producer work in a Java EE/Servlet container?

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6, jaas

The opensource [Java EE 6 Petstore](https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee6) project implements a LoginContext producer to carry out custom user authentication. Below is the source code. 
Why does that work? Is it application server specific or a standard behaviour (for example, enforced by some JSR)?

```
 package org.agoncal.application.petstore.security;

import org.agoncal.application.petstore.util.ConfigProperty;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

/**
 * @author blep
 *         Date: 16/02/12
 *         Time: 07:28
 */
public class LoginContextProducer {

    // ======================================
    // =             Attributes             =
    // ======================================

    @Inject
    private SimpleCallbackHandler callbackHandler;

    // ======================================
    // =          Business methods          =
    // ======================================

    @Produces
    public LoginContext produceLoginContext(@ConfigProperty("loginConfigFile") String loginConfigFileName,
                                            @ConfigProperty("loginModuleName") String loginModuleName) throws LoginException, URISyntaxException {

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", new File(LoginContextProducer.class.getResource(loginConfigFileName).toURI()).getPath());

        try {
            return new LoginContext(loginModuleName, callbackHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ouch!!!");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) with some framework and CDI (who do the @Inject). The CDI and the EJB is in the J2ee specification. The framework do the rest and is out of the specification. That mean, this piece of code, cannot work on a standard tomcat / jboss server.

Comment: Better thinking, I cannot see with sure if have some framework in this code. I think not! and then , it can work in standard!

Comment: I have reviewed these Java EE specs: JAAC (JSR-115), CDI (JSR-299) and JASPIC (JSR-196). None of them states that a custom LoginContext (and then LoginModule) can be integrated into containers that way.

Comment: No, I have asked the wrong question. There is no magic under the hood. The LoginContext producer has nothing to do with the Servlet/Java EE container security. The Petstore project implemented its own security mechanism. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

LoginContext is part of the [Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html).

LoginContextProducer is a CDI "producer" that handles the concern of producing a LoginContext so other classes can inject it. The custom login module is implemented in SimpleLoginModule and it's use is specified in a config file (config.properties).

If you are happy to use the default implementations of JAAS provided by your application server, you don't need to write the custom login module or producer.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the project [Here the POM Maven](https://github.com/stephanrauh/agoncal-petstore-JSE7-ajax/blob/master/pom.xml), if not let anything escape, these main technologies are being used in this project in question:

- EJB (Enterprise JavaBeans)
- JPA (Java Persistence API)
- JSF (Java Server Faces)
- Angular (Framework) and AJAX
- Arquillian (for integral tests)
- Junit (for unit test)

Running on the GlassFish server.

The j2ee specification 6 [here](http://www.sws.bfh.ch/~fischli/courses/eadj/ejb/doc/javaee_platform-6_0-fr-spec.pdf) says you can use dependencies, then code is in the standard. If your question was if this project could work with original / native dependencies of J2ee, then I would answer no, you would have the dependencies for this project to be compiled.